# ¿ Por qué en la última posición de este array no obtengo el nombre dle archivo en PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Cuando listo los archivos de un directorio con **PHP**, desde una consulta `$.post` en **Ajax Jquery**, el nombre del último archivo me lo lista con unos caracteres con esta forma:

> "phpORsOLa"

Por ejemplo:

```
[1577099959]=> string(26) "1577099959_makiVegetal.jpg" [1577100325]=> string(26) "1577100325_makiVegetal.jpg" [1577100409]=> string(9) "phpjv9WZ3" } phpjv9WZ3.
```

Necesito que el último archivo devuelva su nombre correcto.
el código de la función **PHP** es algo así:

```
 foreach (glob($pathtosearch) as $filename)
        {
           var_dump($filename);
           $file_array[filectime($filename)]=basename($filename);

        }
        ksort($file_array);
        return $file_array;
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual es la lista de archivos? tal vez ese archivo existe?

Comment: ¿Esta obtención de listado de ficheros ocurre justo después de una subida de un fichero a tu servidor? Parece el típico nombre temporal que genera PHP cuando subes un fichero antes de ser renombrado. ¿Puede ser que tu código se esté ejecutando antes de que el archivo se renombre?

Comment: ¿Qué estás obteniendo y qué esperas obtener? Lo necesito para ayudarte. También dime qué te devuelve hacerle un var_dump a tu array, quiero saber cuántos elementos te marca y los tipos de dato.

Comment: Hola a todos, gracias por responder... ¿ocurria despues de una subida por ajax? creo que se debía al típico problema de la asincronicidad de ajax osea que antes de recibir la respuesta ya estaba decolviendo el valor incompleto, lo resolví encadenando dos peticiones por ajax una para subir el archivo que devolvía el nombre mediante un Json y otra que enviaba ese mismo nombre con el resto de datos al archivo php. así no hubo problema.